# I'm unable to update my state data in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component name Home inside which I update the state data on two basis. First one is, if my nextProps is different from prevState. Second one is, I change the state data inside a function which is not changed(this is the issue).

Here is the code:

```
class Home extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("in constructor props =", this.props.mainData);
    this.state = {
        data: null,
        isFetch: false,
        clickEvent: false,
        menuData:-1
    }
    this.changeData=this.changeData.bind(this);
}

changeData(option) {
    
    let temp;
    switch (option) {
        case "Upcoming":
            console.log("Upcoming");
            //upcoming is the function in different module 
            temp = upcoming(this.props.mainData);
            console.log("temp after upcoming= ",temp)

            //menuData is updated as successfully but data is not
            this.setState({data:temp,menuData:option},()=>{
                console.log("state 
                  data",this.state.data,this.state.menuData);
            });
            break;
     }
      
     static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
         if (nextProps.mainData !== prevState.data) {
             return {
                 data: nextProps.mainData,
                 isFetch: true
             }
         }
        else
           return null;
    }
    
    render() {
         if(this.props.menuData !== this.state.menuData){
              this.changeData(this.props.menuData);
         }
         //some more stuff....
   }
}
```

In the code when I try to update the state data inside switch case of changeData function it doesn't update, but menuData is updated as expected.

What is wrong here. And how can I update the state data?

Comment: `getDerivedStateFromProps` is re-setting it?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova then what should I do to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `changeData(option)` function to arrow function and then try:

```
changeData = (option) =>  {
   ...
 }
```